# How to get file descriptor for an accepted tcp socket in libuv?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, libuv

The POSIX [`accept`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/accept) function returns the descriptor for the socket that has been accepted. However [`uv_accept`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/stream.html?highlight=uv_accept#c.uv_accept) returns an error indicator instead.

How to get the file descriptor then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question can be slightly reformulated as:

> Extracting the file descriptor out of a handle

Ironically, that is the title of a section of the migration guide to libuv 1.0 (see [here](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/migration_010_100.html) for further details).

Before version 1.0, the not recommend way to do that was accessing the internals of the library as it follows:

```
handle->io_watcher.fd
```

Since libuv v1.0, the recommend way is using [`uv_fileno`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/handle.html#c.uv_fileno) instead.
The documentation states that:

> Gets the platform dependent file descriptor equivalent.
>   The following handles are supported: TCP, pipes, TTY, UDP and poll. [...]

Therefore, it depends on what version of libuv you are using which is the best way to get it out of a handle.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [`uv_fileno`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/handle.html#c.uv_fileno) function on the client `uv_stream` for that.

On Linux and Darwin the returned [`uv_os_fd_t`](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/misc.html#c.uv_os_fd_t) is alias for an `int`, so you can do the following:

```
uv_tcp_t *client;
int conn_s;

// ...

uv_accept(server, (uv_stream_t*) client);
uv_fileno((uv_handle_t *)client, &conn_s);
printf("%d", conn_s);
```

Comment: That's bad style and invokes undefined behviour if the `typedef` changes to something else than `int`. Use `uv_handle_t` and let the compiler convert. This allows the compilert to report potential problems for the conversion.

Comment: however I don't understand your concern. the compiler does report if the conversion is problematic, e.g. if I change to `long conn_s;`, then it gives `warning:
      incompatible pointer types passing 'long *' to parameter of type
      'uv_os_fd_t *' (aka 'int *') [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    uv_fileno((uv_handle_t *)client, &conn_s);`

Comment: 1) It is not my answer and I comment on general bad practice, not something directly related to the question. 2) You tell the compiler explictly not to warn - that's what casts are for! Never use a cast if you don't know about **all** implications and accept them. If you have to pass two pointers to potentially different types, use two variables, pass their pointers and assign one to the other without cast. A good compiler will likely generate the same code as with questionable (at best) code.

Comment: okay, but this has nothing to do with the conversion between the `uv_os_fd_t` and `int` in question, which is done implicitly, wihout any cast.
as for the other casts, libuv guarantees that every handle [can be cast](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/handle.html) to `uv_handle_t`. also `uv_tcp_t` [can be cast to](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/tcp.html#uv-tcp-t-tcp-handle) `uv_stream_t`

Comment: There is no conversion betweeo `int` and `uv_os_fd_t`! There is a **cast** between pointers thereof and I tried to make clear this **is** bad. If you don't see the difference, please recap about pointers and the cast operator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134296/discussion-between-midiparse-and-olaf).

Comment: No. Just that: I refer to you using three differnt type(name)s for ``client`, if that helps.